# Store Vagrant VM in custom folder

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I want to specify folder where Vagrant will store my VM.

I need it only for one VM, so I don't want to modify VirtualBox.xml `defaultMachineFolder` or change `VBOX_USER_HOME` environment variable.

**What is the right way to do it in Vagrantfile?**

I've already tried to add the following lines:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.customize ["createvm", "--name", "name", "--basefolder", "path"]
end
```

It creates VM folder on the path I specified, but it also duplicate it in the 
`~/VirtualBox VMs` folder and add the wrong VM path to the VirtualBox.xml.

Also I've tried to use groups:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb| 
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/subpath"] 
end
```

But it only creates a subfolder in the `~/VirtualBox VMs`.

Please help!

Comment: This is a great question. I know you already said you didn't want to move the `defaultMachineFolder` but that seems like it would solve your problem. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36114947/5240327) for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was not easy but at least I learn a good thing. I will make it as an answer even if you don't find the answer you expected. (sorry in advance)

so first:

> It creates VM folder on the path I specified, but it also duplicate it
>   in the  ~/VirtualBox VMs folder and add the wrong VM path to the
>   VirtualBox.xml.

yes, by default when you see in the vagrant output something like

```
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
```

behind the scenes, vagrant runs something like `VBoxManage import ....` so if you also define a `createvm` property, it will run it in addition to the vagrant box import so it creates duplicate. Note the property set in the `provider` block does not override the default one but are running after the default one.

so vagrant does `VBoxManage import .... --disk /path`; when running from VBoxManage, it is easy to change the path specified for disk and save the VM file anywhere.

However when you look the [vagrant code here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_0.rb#L272) it takes the output of the `target path` property when running `VBoxManage import -n /path_to_your_box_ovf_file`and it builds the path from there **so it will be the same path folder for any VM**.

so on top of the ways you already mentioned, to define the path you can use the [`VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-setproperty)

```
VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder /my_custom_path
vagrant up
VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder default
```

the VM files will be creates in your custom_path folder then you reinitialized the VM folder to its default location. (I did not try but as Vagrantfile is a ruby script you could even run the `VBoxManage setproperty` from the Vagrantfile)