# Run a vagrant box from USB drive using vmware across multiple machines

Tags: vagrant, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

I know this question has been asked a few times, but most of the responses are quite old and i cant find a solution that works.

### What i am trying to accomplish:

Run a vagrant box from a USB drive. I have seen a few posts regarding using Virtualbox to do this, but due to the need of excessive config changes, i decided to purchase the vmware vagrant plugin.

### Setup:

The box i am trying this on is https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04. One Mac one, i am `cd`ing into the usb drive, and creating a folder ubuntu, and running:

```
vagrant init; vagrant up --provider vmware_desktop
```

Once boot is complete, i `halt` the box, and safely remove the usb drive. Based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/36857504/7402287, all the files are saved into the usb drive itself.

Upon plugging in to a second Mac, i cd into the usb drive, and run vagrant up. This is where my issue starts. i am greeted with this message:

```
An error occurred while executing `vmrun`, a utility for controlling
VMware machines. The command and output are below:

Command: ["start", "/Volumes/ssd/vagrant_vms/ubuntu16/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_desktop/long-number/ubuntu-16.04-amd64.vmx", "nogui", {:notify=>[:stdout, :stderr], :timeout=>45}]

Stdout: 2018-06-20T13:26:06.932| ServiceImpl_Opener: PID 94584
Error: The operation was canceled

Stderr:
```

### This i have tried:

- making sure `umask` is 022.
- killing all vmware fusion processes and trying again

### Ideal solution

Ideally, the solution should be able to `init` and `up` a vagrant box in the usb drive using vmware plugin, and work with both vmware fusion and vmware workstation.